# I am building a toast notification in React - bug causing re-render of first set of users and not removing all notifications

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toast

I am building a toast notifications section in React. It takes an array of users to shout out and displays up to 3 notifications at a time. Each notification should be deleted five seconds after appearing or when the close icon is clicked on the notification. When a notification is closed automatically or manually, the next new notification should appear until there are no more notifications. These should also delete in turn.

The current behaviour is buggy in the following way:

1. The first three notifications refresh once before the flow begins. I have logged and nothing is re-rendering to cause this.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Notification from '../Notification';
import styles from './ToastNotifications.module.css';

const ToastNotifications = ({ liveUsers }) => {
const [toastList, setToastList] = useState([]);
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(3);

useEffect(() => {
    setToastList(liveUsers.slice(0, 3));
}, [liveUsers]);

const removeAndAddUser = (removeIndex) => {
    setToastList((prevList) =>
        prevList.map((item, index) =>
            index !== removeIndex ? item : { ...item, fade: true }
        )
    );

    setTimeout(() => {
        setToastList((prevList) =>
            [
                ...prevList.slice(0, removeIndex),
                ...prevList
                    .slice(removeIndex + 1)
                    .filter((item) => !item.fade),
                liveUsers[currentIndex]
            ].filter(Boolean)
        );
        setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
    }, 250);
};

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (toastList.length && liveUsers.length) {
            removeAndAddUser(0);
        }
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    };
}, [toastList, liveUsers, currentIndex]);

const removeUser = (user) => {
    const index = toastList.findIndex((item) => item.key === user.key);
    removeAndAddUser(index);
};

return (
    <div className={styles.toastContainer}>
        {toastList.map((user, index) => {
            return (
                <Notification
                    key={index}
                    user={user}
                    onClose={removeUser}
                />
            );
        })}
    </div>
);
};`
```

Here's the component where the call to the backend is made:

`
const App = () => {
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('url')
        .then((res) => {
            setUsers(res.data.data);
        });
}, []); 

const liveUsers = users.slice(0, 10);

return (
        <ToastNotifications liveUsers={liveUsers} />
);
};
```

Would greatly appreciate any help you can provide to prevent these bugs because I've lost count of the different things I've tried!

I have tried rewriting these useEffects a thousand times to no avail - I appreciate that's not much help but I've got total code blindness now from amount of times I've tried!